# Images are not being displayed when height is set to wrap_content in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What am I trying to do?

Display 20 images vertically. Have to request for the next 20 images when scrolled to the last image (pagination or infinite scroll).

Whats happening?

Using recyclerview with height set to wrap_content: None of the images are being displayed.

Using recylerview with height set to match_parent: I could see the images, but the following request is getting called when the 5th image is being displayed. But i wanted it to be called when scrolled to last image.

### Heading

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="technology.nine.moviedb.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_movie">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main_activity.java

```
package technology.nine.moviedb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import technology.nine.moviedb.adapter.MovieAdapter;
import technology.nine.moviedb.api.ApiClient;
import technology.nine.moviedb.api.ApiInterface;
import technology.nine.moviedb.model.Movie;
import technology.nine.moviedb.model.MovieResponse;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String API_KEY = "9c7b8cc9de4995efcf3705b49f54dca8";
    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentPage = 1;
    int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(R.layout.item_movie, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        fetchData();
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("progress bar", "called");
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY, currentPage);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                movieAdapter.addAll(movies);

                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                            isScrolling = true;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        currentItems = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        totalItems = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        scrollOutItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                        if(isScrolling & (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)){
                            isScrolling = false;
                            currentPage += 1;
                            fetchData();
                        }
                    }
                });
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MovieAdapter.java

```
package technology.nine.moviedb.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import technology.nine.moviedb.GlideApp;
import technology.nine.moviedb.R;
import technology.nine.moviedb.api.ApiClient;
import technology.nine.moviedb.model.Movie;

/**
 * Created by Ganesh on 25-02-2018.
 */

public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> movies;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public MovieAdapter(int rowLayout, Context context) {
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.title.setText(movies.get(position).getTitle());

        String img_url_path = ApiClient.IMAGE_URL + movies.get(position).getPosterPath();

        GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(img_url_path)
                .override(holder.poster.getWidth(), holder.poster.getHeight())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .into(holder.poster);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout moviesLayout;
        ImageView poster;

        public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item_movie);
            poster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }

    }

    public void addAll(List<Movie> movies) {
        for(Movie m: movies) {
            add(m);
        }
    }

    private void add(Movie m) {
        movies.add(m);
        notifyItemInserted(movies.size() - 1);
    }

}
```

Github [link](https://github.com/ganeshmunisifreddy/MovieDB) for this project.

Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried calling it before setting adapter. Even though images are not appearing. @ADM

Comment: I think you need to give width or height any of them should be fixed.

Comment: @GaneshMunisifreddy try this `totalItems = movieAdapter.getItemCount();` in `onScrolled` your API is 20 items ryt ? each time ?

Comment: @Shalu - I want the ImageView with width 'match_parent' and height 'wrap_content'.

Comment: @SantanuSur - I tried `totalItems = movieAdapter.getItemCount();`. It didn't work and yeah default results for API is 20 items per page.

Comment: @GaneshMunisifreddy i have added the answer please check !!

Comment: @SantanuSur - I tried it. Images are not appearing if I set recylerView height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: i will try to find out and update !!

Comment: @SantanuSur cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine. Try modifying the condition inside the onScrolled function as below:

```
int buffer = 3;//you can modify this accordingly.
if(isScrolling & (scrollOutItem > (totalItems - buffer))){
    //call fetchData();
}
```

Comment: Will give it a try.

Comment: Its working :) but only when I set recyclerView height to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

as your list is horzontal you should know match_parent give fixed size to list so it will fill 5 item and give no more space consider using wrap_content for dynamic size

item_movie.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"/>
```

wrap_content might work depending on case for height so check it first

and if want to keep the aspect ratio you can use weight with zero height android will do the work

```
   <ImageView
    **android:scaleType="centerInside"**
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

> android:scaleType="centerInside"

will render image to keep it scaling

Comment: I want to set imageView height and width to aspect ratio like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zx-JdGp6w5RC3Sy2HN9Qrxp-bgtYBKZHHNU9ItgEcA-zxX0Whj4m5ORvBjBucVWSN1wc=w1918-h989).

Comment: did you set layout_width

Answer (score 0):

item_movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_movie">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

set fix height of layout---------50dp,60dp,100dp etc...